# Not able to login as a root in mysql from localhost through commandline

Tags: linux, mysql, login

I am running MySQL 5.0.75-0ubuntu10.5 on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty. When I try to login as a root to MySQL

`# mysql -u root -h localhost -padmin`

I get following error

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2)`

But if I try using `phpmyadmin` http://localhost/phpmyadmin I can login using same credentials.

There are 3 entries for user "root" in mysql.user table with 3 different hosts

- localhost
- 127.0.0.1
- indrik (hostname)

Encrypted Password for all these 3 entries is identical. I tried all 3 hostnames with `-h` argument, still no luck.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try connecting to localhost using TCP instead with the following additional command line argument:

```
--protocol=TCP
```

You can also make sure you have the correct socket file my checking /etc/my.cnf :

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If that states a different socket than the one in your error you can specify it on the command line with `--socket=path`, i.e. `--socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

Comment: I found out that in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` the location of mysql socket was defined as `/tmp/mysql.sock` but in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` it was `/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock`. So by providing `--socket=/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock` as an argument I can login to mysql as a root user.

Comment: @greenmang0: You should be able to fix that in the my.cnf under a client configuration header so you don't always have to specify the socket file.